# Jquery countdown, 24hour and rules for weekends

Tags: jquery, jquery-countdown

Ive added the code in here 
When it hits friday after 11.00 it should countdown to money @ 11.00 
Any suggestions / help to get here?
Also: The CountDown-timer should also be able to check if its a holiday here in Denmark (not sure about this function, maybe a database to control that part, because the holidays will come in variables hmm?)
http://jsfiddle.net/srwpyac0/24/

HTML:

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function ShowTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    if (now.getHours() > 11) {
        var hrs = 11 - now.getHours() + 24;
    } else {
        var hrs = 11 - now.getHours();
    }
    var mins = 60 - now.getMinutes();
    var secs = 60 - now.getSeconds();

    timeLeft = "You now have " + hrs + ' Hour(s) ' + mins + ' minuts ' + secs + ' seconds' + " To complete the order, and make sure the delivery will reach to you in 1-3 days";
    $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
}

var countdown;

function StopTime() {
    clearInterval(countdown);

}

setInterval(ShowTime, 1000);
```

Comment: please elaborate your problem a little more, it looks like your problem has two parts- 1) something to do be done with counter when it hits friday 2) you want the counter to identify local holidays in your area and change it accordingly (you a need a calendar plugin with list of "off" days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is you want. Please check the code once.

**Javascript:**

```
function ShowTime() {
  var now = new Date();
    if (now.getHours() > 11){
        var hrs =11-now.getHours()+24;
        if(now.getDay() == 5){
            var hrs = hrs + 48;
        }
    }else{
  var hrs = 11-now.getHours();
         }

  var mins = 60-now.getMinutes();
  var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();

      timeLeft = "You now have "+hrs+' Hour(s) '+mins+' minuts '+secs+' seconds' +" To complete the order, and make sure the delivery will reach to you in 1-3 days";
  $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
}

var countdown;
function StopTime() {
    clearInterval(countdown);

}

setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
```

Fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srwpyac0/31/)

Comment: Thank you I added some extra value to the fiddle, which I think fixed it.
http://jsfiddle.net/srwpyac0/34/

Now i just need to find a solution for the holy days in Denmark hmm